# 2000s horror movie about a witch

Tags: identify-this-movie

The movie is about a group of people that were trying to confirm (i think) the existence of the blair witch, so they went to a woods and started finding clues of whitchcraft and ritual sacrifices.

Then they go to a house or a building or something and started dying (because of the witch’s curse?)

The plot twist at the end was that one of them was actually the one that killed the others, not the whitch as we see some video footage of him killing and hiding the bodies.  There was footage of him dragging a female body and hiding her in a closet.

I saw this movie when I was young, so it was “probably” released prior to 2002.  Horror genre, probably American .

I don’t think it’s the movie [Blair Witch Project](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0185937/?ref_=nv_sr_2).  I read the synopsis and it didn’t match what I remember.

Comment: Sorry, but if you know this movie was about the Blair witch, why not look up the franchise on Wikipedia, for example?

Comment: @Walt I looked the movies that have the word “blair” in the title on imdb, didn’t know that I can look up the whole franchise! Thanks for the hint

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Could be [Book of Shadows: Blair Witch 2](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Shadows:_Blair_Witch_2)

> A group of tourists arrive in Burkittsville, Maryland after seeing The Blair Witch Project (1999) to explore the mythology and phenomenon, only to come face to face with their own neuroses and possibly the witch herself.

In the end,

> After a jump cut, the audience sees that Jeff, Stephen, and Kim have been arrested. They report to the police that Tristen was possessed and committed the crimes. Each is interrogated separately, with the police showing each person footage of their crimes. Security camera footage shows Kim killing the store cashier by stabbing the store cashier in the neck with the cashier's nail file. Surveillance camera footage shows a naked Jeff arranging Erica's clothes, and putting her dead body in the closet. Jeff's video shows the group interrogating Tristen, accusing her of being a witch, and Stephen pushing her over the banister (but not Tristen putting the rope around her own neck). All three, close to a nervous breakdown, vehemently deny doing any of those things and they insist that the footage is not how the events happened.

Comment: I think that’s the one! I’ll watch it asap. Thank you very much ~

Comment: glad I could help.